# Wait for Localstorage then call api

Tags: api, ionic-framework, angular6, local-storage, ionic4

I get settings from user inputs and store it by localstorage. I use this data in the API Call.

```
 userlocation;
 userservice ;
 usercategory ;

 constructor(public http: HttpClient, public storage : Storage) { }

 getListings(){

 this.storage.get('area').then((userlocation) => {
  this.userlocation =  userlocation;

  console.log(this.userlocation)
 });

  this.storage.get('ser').then((userservice) => {
  this.userservice =  userservice;

  console.log(this.userlocation)
 });

  return  this.http.get(this.api_url+"?location="+ this.userlocation+ 
  "&ser= " + this.userservice)

 }
```

the problem that the api call happens before localstorage get the data.
How I can make The api call wait for localstorage

Comment: why having same variable name when you're taking different value from the localStorage??

Comment: yes it's I problem but I think this not solve the proplem

Answer (score 0):

Using async and await you can resolve this.

```
userlocation;
 userservice ;
 usercategory ;

 constructor(public http: HttpClient, public storage : Storage) { }

 async getListings(){ 

 await this.storage.get('area').then((userlocation) => {
  this.userlocation =  userlocation;

  console.log(this.userlocation);

    await this.storage.get('ser').then((userservice) => {
      this.userservice =  userservice;

      console.log(this.userlocation)
    });
 });



  return  this.http.get(this.api_url+"?location="+ this.userlocation+ 
  "&ser= " + this.userservice)

 }
```

Comment: I get this error 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.

Comment: yes check the function name `getLIstings()` in my answer

Comment: I try it by get one key from localstorge. the api call not happend. that's my page code :  this.AuthService.getListings().then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.items = data;
      });

Comment: I'm not understanding

Comment: the API call not happen